# ASP.NET MVC / IIS Multiple URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm getting a request to set up the following scenario:

1. A base URL that, when entered, directs to an ASP.NET MVC site as usual. User can navigate through the site (many controllers) using that URL and it functions as-expected.
2. Many other URLs, different than the "base url" which would, behind the scenes, display content from a specific controller action. For example:

http://subsite.com: actually displays, by default http://baseurl.com/subsites/1 with a layout that limits the site navigation, but always keeps the user seeing the subsite's URL as their root address.

Is this possible with IIS 7.5 / MVC 4?

Thanks!

Comment: This is possible via IIS URL Rewrite and/or MVC routing. Which do you prefer?

Comment: I'd prefer MVC routing if possible!